# Add text to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, append, jtextarea

I'm trying to append text to a JTextArea. I understand how to add text through an event listener, but I can't seem to fathom how to add the text if, per say, calling a method from a main-method. The text is appended to the JTextArea just fine but the JTextArea component isn't updated/repainted/revalidated/validated (or whatever you're supposed to say :-)).

GUITest

```
public class GUITest {
    private GUI gui = null;

    public GUITest() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gui = GUI.getInstance();

                gui.createAndShowGUI();

                gui.addTxt("Test1");

                gui.addTxt("Test2");

                gui.addTxt("Test3");

                gui.addTxt("Test4");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUITest();
    }
}
```

GUI

```
public class GUI extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ConsolePanel console;
    private static GUI instance;

    private GUI() {
        console = new ConsolePanel();

        add(console);
    }

    public static GUI getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) instance = new GUI();

        return instance;
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create window
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GUI");

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setBackground(Color.decode("#333333"));
        f.setResizable(false);

        // Create the content pane
        JComponent c = new GUI();

        c.setOpaque(false);
        f.setContentPane(c);

        // Draw the window
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addTxt(String txt) {
        console.addTxt(txt);
    }
}
```

ConsolePanel

```
public class ConsolePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea console;

    public ConsolePanel() {
        console = new JTextArea("Init...", 10, 10);

        add(console);
    }

    public void addTxt(String txt) {
        console.append(txt);
    }
}
```

How do I implement the addTxt-method correctly, so that the "Test1", "Test2"... also are added and displayed on the text component?

Fixed:

Changed the line `JComponent c = new GUI()` to `JComponent c = instance`.

Comment: Somewhere things are likely not wired appropriately, but where I can't see based on the code above. You should consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. Note that your sscce should not use MigLayout or any other outside dependencies. Keep it simple.

Comment: My guess: you may be shadowing a variable in code not shown.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan: please delete your misleading comment. There is never a need to call `revalidate()` after calling `append(...)` on a JTextArea.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've tried to remove all unnecessary code now. It compiles and runs just fine. But the lines are not added.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan I tried, and also read, as Hovercraft Full Of Eels noted, that the revalidate shouldn't be called when using append.

Comment: Your code seems to confuse GUI and TestGUI and thus will not compile for me. Same for ConsolePanel and TestConsolePanel -- did you test your code before posting? Please fix.

Comment: Where is your TestGUI class????????

Comment: @user3437460: I think that it's the same as his GUI class, but this is all very confusing.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've fixed the errors now. :-)

Comment: Looks like to me that he is recreating new instances instead of calling the instance method to append the text. Thus not seeing any updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new TestGUI (or GUI depending on how you name it) in the createAndShowGUI method, thus you have two of these beasts. Don't do that. Create only one.

Comment: You're right. I've changed it to `JComponent c = instance` instead.

Comment: @user2832479: exactly. myself, I'd get the createAndShowGUI method out of the GUI or TestGUI class entirely as it does not belong there.

Comment: - And it fixed the problem. You're my hero! :-)

Comment: How would you implement the "createAndShowGUI" then?

Comment: @user2832479 In the first place, I don't see any point of creating a new JFrame instance inside your JPanel. You don't have to create a new JFrrame `JFrame f = new JFrame("GUI");` inside your JPanel class. If you need a reference, at most you pass in the reference through the constructor. Your coding structure needs clarity. It should be simple i.e.: JFrame holds JPanel. JPanel holds other JComponent. That's it.

Comment: @user2832479: you would place createAndShow in the same class that holds the main. You create a JFrame when you need it where you need, it, but not inside the GUI/TestGUI class.

Comment: Ah, I've moved the method to the main. Thank you. :-)